# how can I update children and insert new child in one to many relationship in EF

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I have one to many relationship between ItemPrice and ItemPriceHistory classes my mapping follows below:

```
public class ItemPrice 
{
    public long ID {get; set;}
    public List<ItemPriceHistory> ItemPriceHistories { get; set; }

    public ItemPrice()
    {
       ItemPriceHistories = new List<ItemPriceHistory>();
    }
}

public class ItemPriceHistory
{
    public ItemPrice ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public long ID {get; set;}
    public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }
}


modelBuilder.Entity<ItemPriceHistory>()
            .HasRequired(h => h.ItemPrice)
            .WithMany(p => p.ItemPriceHistories)
            .Map(h => h.MapKey("ItemPrice_ID"));
```

I am trying to update previous ItemPriceHistory Entries and try to add a new ItemPriceHistory Entry.

```
    var dbItemPrice = repo.Std.Get<ItemPrice>()
                                    .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == id);                

            if (dbItemPrice == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }                

            //query for matching ItemPriceHistory
            var dbPriceHistories = repo.Std.Get<ItemPriceHistory>()
                                    .Include(h=>h.ItemPrice, repo.Std)
                                    .Where(h => h.ItemPrice.ID == ItemPrice.ID)
                                    .OrderByDescending(h => h.ModifiedDate);

            #region new history entry

            var newHistoryEntry = new ItemPriceHistory();
            newHistoryEntry.IsCurrent = true;
            newHistoryEntry.ItemPrice = dbItemPrice;

            //copy the current pirce list and update it with new history entry
            var currentPriceHistoryList = dbPriceHistories.ToList();
            currentPriceHistoryList.ForEach(h => { h.IsCurrent = false; });
            currentPriceHistoryList.Add(newHistoryEntry);

            //new price list
            var newHistoryList = new List<ItemPriceHistory>();
            currentPriceHistoryList.ForEach(h => newHistoryList.Add(new ItemPriceHistory
                                            {
                                                ItemPrice = h.ItemPrice,
                                                IsCurrent = h.IsCurrent,
                                            }
                                    ));
            #endregion

            //delete current price histories
            dbItemPrice.ItemPriceHistories.Clear(); 


            // add histories to database
            newHistoryList.ForEach(h => dbItemPrice.ItemPriceHistories.Add(h));

            Context.SaveChanges();
```

When it calls SaveChanges(), I get the following error:

> {"An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign
>   key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property
>   will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the
>   source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be
>   made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types.
>   See the InnerException for details."}
>
> InnerException: {"A relationship from the 'ItemPriceHistory_ItemPrice'
>   AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity
>   constraints, a corresponding 'ItemPriceHistory_ItemPrice_Source' must
>   also in the 'Deleted' state."}

I do not want to delete my `ItemPrice_Source`. I just want to delete current `ItemPriceHistories` and update previous `ItemPriceHistories` and add new `ItemPriceHistory` entry. How can I safely update `ItemPriceHistory` entries along with new `ItemPriceHistory` entry?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use an example that shoudl fit into your STD generic repository class.
Looks like you are using this pattern.

Did you try something like

```
 public virtual IQueryable<T> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, bool withTracking = false)
    {
        if (withTracking)
            return QuerySet.Where(predicate);
        return QuerySet.Where(predicate).AsNoTracking();
    }


//    then
var iph_list = RepItemPriceHist.GetList(h=>h.ItemPrice.Id == VarID)

 //  psuedo code... foreach history entity entitity.Iscurrent = false;
```

so now these entities should be changed and managed by the statemanager.
add teh new entries....

```
// add histories to database
          newHistoryList.ForEach(h => dbItemPrice.ItemPriceHistories.Add(h));
 Context.SaveChanges();
```

I didnt understand why you need to **CLEAR** the collection
Arent you updating existing records and adding new ones ?
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just load the `ItemPrice` *including* all current `ItemPriceHistories`, then set the `IsCurrent` flag of those histories to `false` and add a new history with `IsCurrent = true`? Change tracking should update the current histories and insert a new one to the database:

```
var dbItemPrice = repo.Std.Get<ItemPrice>()
    .Include(i => i.ItemPriceHistories, repo.Std)
    .SingleOrDefault(i => i.ID == id);                

if (dbItemPrice == null)
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

foreach (var history in dbItemPrice.ItemPriceHistories)
    history.IsCurrent = false;

dbItemPrice.ItemPriceHistories.Add(new ItemPriceHistory { IsCurrent = true });

Context.SaveChanges();
```